# Как разделить текст на несколько колонок?

Tags: html, css

[image: скриншот]

У меня тут на футере есть список:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fbox">
  <h4>Xidmətlər</h4>
  <ul class="big">
    <li><a href="odsonduren.html" title="">Odsöndürənlər</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Yanğın təhlükəsizlik sistemləri</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Müşahidə</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Layihə və planın qurulması</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" title="">Monitorinq</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Təxliyyə qapılarının quraşdırılması</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Qanunvericilik</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Avto dayanacaq sistemlərinin quraşdırılması</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Как мне разделить его на две равные части по 4 элемента слева и справа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для разделения текста на 2 колонки вы можете воспользоваться свойством [`column-count`](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count).

```css
.big {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fbox">
  <h4>Xidmətlər</h4>
  <ul class="big">
    <li><a href="odsonduren.html" title="">Odsöndürənlər</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Yanğın təhlükəsizlik sistemləri</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Müşahidə</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Layihə və planın qurulması</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" title="">Monitorinq</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Təxliyyə qapılarının quraşdırılması</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Qanunvericilik</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title=""> Avto dayanacaq sistemlərinin quraşdırılması</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Блогадарю вас..